# Why the submitted paper remains "With Editor" or "Editor Assigned" for more than 1 months?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

We had submitted a research article to one of the journals in the field of *Computer Science* one(1) months back. Within 2 days of submission, the status changed from **Submitted to journal** to **With Editor**.

However, it has been more than 1 months that the paper has been showing this status as **With Editor**.

I do understand that majority of CS journals paper quickly can not find a suitable reviewer for review. However, I don't think it is justified to wait for more than 1 months for the same to go for **Review**.

Should I send a gentle reminder to the editorial board? Or, is it too early.

We are worried because the if the results of the paper gets *accepted*, then we can progress our work to another level.

N.B. I don't think it is decent to **Withdraw** the manuscript.

*I did search [previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75315/status-of-submitted-article-changes-the-date-but-status-remain-from-with-editor), but could not find it useful.*

Comment: Seems strange to me.  But what do I know?  I was in a different field.  For a mathematics paper, you would not send a query until 6 months have passed.  Some would say, a year.  It seems strange that you have to wait for publication before you can continue your work.

Comment: Likely the editor is in the process of lining up reviewers who agree to review the paper. Or, it is under discussion by the editors if it should even go out for review. These things all take time, and should not prevent you from continuing to make progress.

Comment: I did not downvote, but one reason for the downvote may be that you ask totally different questions in the title (Why is that?) and in the body (What should I do?).

Comment: @Dirk I have both the things listed because in some journals it shows "With Editor" and in some journals it shows "Editor Assigned". So, to make it a general question, I have listed. However, you could edit for clarity. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how I could edit. I don't know which of the two questions you want to have answered. But for the "Why" question: Can be many reasons (editor did not find a reviewer, editor is away from mail, editor did forget to click "in review" button, editor is lazy…). As for the "What to do" question: Ask your advisor what a typical time for a query for this particular field is.

Comment: In some submission systems, when an editor sends an email to a potential reviewer, the reviewer needs to click on a link to either accept or decline to review. If the invited reviewer neither accepts nor declines to review, the submission system remains 'stuck' until the invitation times out (usually 2-4 weeks). Then only after the timeout can the editor invite a different reviewer. This could delay the 'under review' phase.

Comment: By the way, waiting for an acceptance to progress with your work is not a good thing to do. Publication in a journal might take a long time (more than 12 months). If your later work needs to cite your previous work that is not published yet, you could create a technical report out of the previous work and cite that report.

Comment: But, why is this question getting negative vote? I don't find any sufficient/necessary reason to justify the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a different field.

Best source to answer your question is unlikely to be on this site.

Do you know anybody personally who's published in that journal and who would be able to answer your question from experience?

Next, check the instructions to authors on the journal publisher's website, where the publication work-flow might be explained, including any slowdown in the process.

Once you've checked this, if you cannot find any specific information that would answer your question, send an email to the journal editor you're meant to have as your main contact.

Assuming you get an answer, you'll be clearer on the publication schedule for your article.

Agreeing with your N.B. If you're currently not clear about the situation, withdrawing the article without further update might be a waste of time, for all involved, and you could alienate the editor of a journal you're potentially interested in publishing in further.