# what should i do in this situation , please?

Tags: peer-review, journals, editors

I got `minor revisions` for my paper and `sent it by 20/9` , `in 23/9 I got change in the status to be "with the editor"` then I got change in the date in `5/10 and the status is "with the editor"` too. Now I asked the editor for the expected time that I will got the final decision and his reply was "`The manuscript is currently with the editor for evaluation and you will be notified once the decision has been rendered.`".

Does his reply means it will take more time , please ?

Does the final decision will take all the time with minor revisions, I know that the time will differ from journal to another and depend on the editors but is there any expected time I can guess ?

also what is the difference between the two dates that changed and the status still itself "with the editor" ?

what is the the status that I should wait it ?

Comment: Once a decision is made they will tell you. Yes, nothing to do but wait.

Comment: does the minor revisions take all this time ?

Comment: The journal has a workflow process. Many other articles are in the pipeline requiring attention as well. The editors are (generally) volunteers who have other jobs. Yes, it all takes time but they will get to it when it is the next item in the queue.

Comment: I got it but excuse me , there are papers revised after my paper but accepted before mine . the minor revisions i got not much . it is just replaced or checked some words

Comment: And those may well have gone through different editors. Things were easier back in the day - you sent off an envelope with a submission, and at some point got back an envelope. Instead of checking on the status, go take a walk or have an appropriate beverage with friends. Learn to accept what you can't influence.

Comment: Re: "also what is the difference between the two dates that changed and the status still itself "with the editor" ?": [Status of submitted article changes the date but status remain from 'With Editor' to 'With Editor'](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75315/17254)

Comment: The answer to the title  question, "What should I do ...?" is relax.